# Query to Count and reset based on a field

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, generator

Need help with getting the query right...
I have a table `tablA` with the following records:

```
Name,  Item
-----------
John,  Pen
Alex,  Crayon
John,  Ruler
John,  Pencil
Bryan, Marker
Alex,  Sticker
```

I need a query to 
a) number the record a person is having and reset that value for new person.
b) sort by Name, then by Item

The followings result is what I will like to have:

```
Name,  Item,    Cnt
-------------------
Alex,  Crayon,  1
Alex,  Sticker, 2
Bryan, Marker,  1
John,  Pen,     1
John,  Pencil,  2
John,  Ruler,   3
```

I am thinking of something like.... (but I don't know how to reset the `Cnt` when new person appears):

```
select Name, Item, @cntrow: @cntrow+1 as Cnt from tablA, 
(select @cntrow:=0) rx 
order by Name, Item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use another variable:

```
select
    @cntrow := case when @grp <> Name then  1 else @cntrow + 1 end as Cnt,
    @grp := Name as Name, 
    Item
from tablA
cross join(select @cntrow:=0, @grp := null) rx 
order by Name, Item
```

Comment: Thank you. That did it. But it seems that I need to do sorting first.